# IOS InterfaceBuilder- Managing Many UIViews in a single ViewController Scene

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

I would like to handle in a single Scene many UIViews. Some of those views will remain hidden at runtime until some specific events happen. When i'm drawing with the interface builder i see a confusing scene since those views that on runtime time are hidden are visible in design time.
Even when flagging an UIView as hidden it is still visible (just a little less opaque)
As example consider a simple game where an UIView that cover all the scene should be visible when the user press "pause" (when such view appears it should be possible to glimpse the game as alpha is >0)

How is the proper way to deal with this situation? is programmatically design the only solution?

Thank you and kind regards

Nicolò

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic design is not the only answer.  You could use containerViews, or subViews with childViewControllers.  Then you can design each view in its own ViewController in IB, and bring them in when you need them.  Google all of those terms, and experiment a bit with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.